# Is inflation voting chain based?

Tags: inflation, accounts

If I have 3 accounts, lets call them `A`, `B` and `C` and you set inflation in chained manner like so:

- `A` sets its inflation destination to `B`
- `B` sets its inflation destination to `C`

Would `A` votes be counted for `C`'s total voting count?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No. Inflation voting cannot be chained**

This isn't explicitly mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/inflation.html#how-inflation-voting-works) so by default you have to fall back to looking at the code for the current implementation.

Reading the follow `AccountFrame::processForInflation` method from the [source code:](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/d6fc518b80afa9731557120f831df06b592db1b0/src/ledger/AccountFrame.cpp#L642)

Accounts are selected initially by the following query

```
SELECT
 sum(balance) AS votes, inflationdest FROM accounts WHERE
 inflationdest IS NOT NULL
 AND balance >= 1000000000 GROUP BY inflationdest
 ORDER BY votes DESC, inflationdest DESC LIMIT ?
```

The accounts are then further refined for the dynamic minimum vote amount (calculated based on the XLM in existance)

So due to the SQL query using **groupby** you will not be able to pass on your voting to another account.